# Nonce in Ethereum mining

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, bitcoin

When a block is being mined nonce will be generated so that the nonce is appended with the header hash. Then the resulting hash of that appended value should be less than the target.

The question is Until the correct nonce is generated , will the nonce be appended to the header hash or for each try  the nonce gets appended to the hash produced by the previously appended nonce ?

Answer (score 1):

The nonce is not appended to the header hash, it is part of the header.

A block hash is a hash of the block header, and the nonce is a part of the block header (along with the transaction root, prev block hash, etc.).

When incrementing the nonce, it is incremented as part of the header, and then the entire header is hashed again, and then checked against the target.